# How to understand function declaration like int (*func())[5] and int (&func())[5] in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

Could anyone give me some hint on how to understand these declarations in C programming. Are they some kind of function pointers?

Comment: Find the leftmost identifier (in this case, `func`).  Then work your want out, remembering that `()` and `[]` bind before `*`; IOW, `*a[]` is an array of pointer, where `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, and `*f()` is a function returning pointer, where `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function.  `int (*func())[5]` declares `func` as a function returning a pointer to 5-elelment array of `int`.  `int (&func())[5]` is not a legal C declaration.

Comment: There's no such thing as `int (&func())[5]` in C.

Answer (score 0):

And read Kernighan and Ritchie; the section on declarators in particular. Keep a copy in your bathroom.